# How to run multiple adapters in sails.js

Tags: mysql, mongodb, sails.js

I'm a rookie in sails.js... while working on config folder, connections.js file i have added MYSQL and MongoDB connections...

```
module.exports.connections = {
 appDevMYSQL: {
    adapter: 'sails-mysql',
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'appDev', //optional
    password: 'appDev123', //optional
    database: 'appdev' //optional
  },
  appDevMongo: {
   adapter: 'sails-mongo',
   host: 'localhost',
   port: 27017, 
   database: 'appdev'
    // user: 'username', // password: 'password' 
  } 
}
```

and in same config folder, model.js file I'm trying to access both connections ...

```
module.exports.models = {
  connection: 'appDevMYSQL',
  connection: 'appDevMongo',
}
```

but it some how connecting to Mongo only ...
 when i comment 2nd connection Mongo-'appDevMongo' , MYSQL-'appDevMYSQL' is working fine but I want both to work...
 is that like only ONE connection works? or I'm missing somthig...

Comment: Why do you want to do that in first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you define the connection in config/model.js then this is the default connection that will be used when querying the database.

so in config/models.js you can define only one connection which will act as the default.

If you want to use multiple connections. then define the connections in the same way way as you have defined in config/connections.js

```
module.exports.connections = {
       appDevMYSQL: {
              adapter: 'sails-mysql',
              host: 'localhost',
              user: 'appDev', //optional
              password: 'appDev123', //optional
              database: 'appdev' //optional
       },
       appDevMongo: {
             adapter: 'sails-mongo',
             host: 'localhost',
             port: 27017, 
             database: 'appdev'
             // user: 'username', // password: 'password' 
      } 
}
```

In your models files inside api/models you can define the connection that you want to use.
lets say for User.js Model

```
module.exports ={
           connection : 'appDevMongo',
           attributes : {
                //this will contain model attributes
           }
}
```

lets says for tweets Model  Tweets.js

```
module.exports ={
           connection : 'appDevMYSQL',
           attributes : {
                //this will contain model attributes
           }
}
```